# Making a directory in android sdcard

Tags: android, file-io, sd-card, android-sdcard

i m trying to create directory in sd card through this card.but it is not worked.i put write external storage permission in manifest though it is not working.need urgent help.i had put this code in try catch.but it doesn't enter in catch block.here is my code..

```
try
        {
          File songDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/iAC2013");
           if(!songDirectory.exists())
          {
              songDirectory.mkdirs();
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Directory created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // ShowlistView();
          }
         else
         {
               //ShowlistView();
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Directory AlreadyExists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("","Error While creating file is:::::"+e+"");
        }
```

Comment: what error you have post the logcat..

Comment: File songDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/iAC2013");

Comment: Please upload your AndroidManifest.xml file's code in the question.

Comment: no loagcat occurs but it only shows toast "Directory created" every Time.

Comment: i want to create iAC2013 directory in SDCARD

Answer (score 0):

Try out the Below Code :

```
File sdDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File wwwjdicDir = new File(sdDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/your_folder_name");
            if (!wwwjdicDir.exists()) {
                wwwjdicDir.mkdir();
            }

            if (!wwwjdicDir.canWrite()) {
                return;
            }
```

Comment: Bhavesh.....your code helped me. !wwwjdicDir.canWrite() executes while i runnige code. there was some problem while witing on sdcard.thanks.

Comment: @MikinPatel: you should accept the Answer is it helps you to solve your Problem. so that other User can rely on this answer to solve their issue.

Answer (score 0):

try like

```
       File dir = new File(DEFAULT_STORAGE_LOCATION);
        // test dir for existence and writeability
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            try {
                dir.mkdirs();
            } catch (Exception e) {   
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            if (!dir.canWrite()) {
                   return null;
                 // do your work here
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

If this is your code

```
File songDirectory = new `File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/iAC2013");
```

you need to chagne it to this

```
File songDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/iAC2013");
```

Comment: Why not `new File(directory, name)` ?

Comment: hey i dont have any kind of syntax error...please dont reply this ind of anwer